# Why does NPM throw HTTP Error 400 for Publishing a Package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, npm-publish

I'm attempting to publish an NPM package, called `2680`. There isn't a package/user/org with this name currently, and the rest of my `package.json` seems valid. Here's all the details:

```json
{
  "name": "2680",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A simple & performant library for handling reactive state.",
  "main": "src/2680.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/aarvinr/2680.git"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "keywords": [
    "library",
    "reactive",
    "js",
    "state"
  ],
  "author": "aarvinr",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/aarvinr/2680/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/aarvinr/2680#readme"
}
```

```json
{
  "name": "2680",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "2680",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "license": "MIT"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried running `npm publish --access public`, but it simply returned a cryptic http error `400 Bad Request PUT`, and nothing else.

Comment: I assume you have `npm login` working fine?    Also `2680` seems a very odd name for a package.   Also if you publishing a scope, your name needs that too eg.. `@myscope/2680`

Comment: I do have login working fine, and I don't want a scope for this. `2680` definitely is a weird name :), but it should be valid according to the naming guidelines.

Comment: You don't need `--access public`, none scoped packages are always public.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Keith, makes things easier. Unfortunately that wasn't was causing the problem, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting npm support, it turns out you can't have a package with only numbers in its name - even though this is documented LITERALLY NOWHERE (npm, please do better).

So, the only way to resolve this is to add letters (in my case `2680` has been renamed to [`2680.js`](https://npm.im/2680.js)).

Comment: Glad you got this sorted, I think NPM could have maybe given a better 400 response here, maybe `400 Bad package name PUT`